# GET * Datas from first table connect over same ID

Tags: mysql

i guess that i ask a kind of question like it was ask a thousand times, before, but i dont understand the part in other questions, i hope someone could explain it me at my simple code.

I have two tables

```
TableA -> ID|SITEID|NEXT|...
TABLEB -> ID|SITEID|ANOTHER|...
```

Now i want to catch all results wich are matched by the same SITEID='SITEXY' and TABLEB.ANOTHER='IDXY'. As result i only want to recieve the fields of TABLEA.

At the moment i do it this way, but i get the fields from both tables.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEA, TABLEB WHERE TABLEA.SITEID='SITEXY' AND TABLEB.ANOTHER='IDXY' AND TABLEA.SITEID=TABLEB.SITEID;
```

Mybe its better to use "USING" or "JOIN" but i'm to stupid to understand how it works....:-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can qualify the wildcard with the table from which you want to get the rows:

```
select TABLEA.*
from TABLEA
join TABLEB on TABLEA.SITEID = TABLEB.SITEID
where TABLEA.SITEID = 'SITEXY'
    and TABLEB.ANOTHER = 'IDXY';
```

Also, always use modern explicit join syntax instead of comma based join.

Using aliases, you can make the query bit cleaner:

```
select a.*
from TABLEA a
join TABLEB b on a.SITEID = b.SITEID
where a.SITEID = 'SITEXY'
    and b.ANOTHER = 'IDXY';
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign aliases to both tables, and then select all columns from `TABLEA`:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM TABLEA a
INNER JOIN TABLEB b
    ON a.SITEID = b.SITEID
WHERE a.SITEID = 'SITEXY' AND
      b.ANOTHER = 'IDXY';
```

Aliases make it easier to read and write a query.  Note that I have also replaced your implicit join with an explicit one using `INNER JOIN` and `ON`.  As a general rule, you should avoid writing commas in the `FROM` clause.